# convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It seems really easy but I'm probably missing something, how can I show that the series  $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2-1} $ converges?

Comment: What's its first term?

Comment: You need to sort the indices out.

Comment: Use limit-comparison.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:**

Using partial fraction expansion write the general term as

$$\frac{1}{n^2-1}=\frac{1/2}{n-1}-\frac{1/2}{n+1}$$

Then telescope.

Comment: And feel free to up vote and accept an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}\sim\frac{1}{n^2-1}
$$
so that by the limit comparison test and p-series test ($2>1$), the series in question converges.

Comment: Using $\frac{2}{n^2}$ to compare with can finish the proof right?

Comment: Direct comparison and limit comparison are separate methods, and either one works fine on its own.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to limit comparison, and telescoping, which have already been mentioned in other answers, you can use the integral test or the direct comparison test to show this.

Integral:

$$\begin{align}
\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2-1} &= \frac12\int_2^\infty \left(\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)dx\\
&= \frac12\left(\lim_{b\to\infty}\ln\frac{b-1}{b+1} - \ln\frac13\right)\\
&= \frac{\ln 3}{2} < \infty
\end{align}$$

Direct comparison:

Since $n^2-1 > \frac{n^2}{2}$ for $n\geq 2$, then taking reciprocals, we have $\frac{1}{n^2-1} < \frac{2}{n^2}$, and $\sum\frac{2}{n^2}$ is a convergent p-series.